# Как изменить ширину карты(yandex maps api) при изменении ширины браузера

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Подскажите, как в `yandex maps api` сделать так, чтобы ширина карты изменялась при изменении ширины браузера?
Не смотря на то, что в родительском блоке я могу задать ширину `"width: 100%"`, я обратил внимание, что внутри карт есть тег, где инлайном прописывается ширина:

`<ymaps class="ymaps3x0--map" style="width: 700px; height: 400px; touch-action: none;">`

Если я правильно понимаю, эта ширина устанавливается при монтировании компонента и затем никак не изменяется.

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы ширина карты динамически менялась при изменении ширины экрана?

Answer (score 1):

```js
function mapResize(map){
    map.container.fitToViewport();
}
window.onresize = mapResize(map);
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: А в третьей версии это вроде бы и не требуется. Там карта сама отслеживает изменение контейнера. Попробуйте сами менять размеры окна в примере: https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/examples/cases/create-map